# Match and Extract URL from Wordpress Posts

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache

I found and compile a code so I can retrieve first matching url from my wordpress posts and echo results where necessary. I'm able to do this but I have stuck in a condition when I used below function + code on custompage it works fine. On other hand, when I tried to apply same code on every post by pasting below function in theme's functions.php and call it so my server got halted because of lot of httpd requests and mysql also went down until I remove this code and clear cache to normalize my server.
Code added in theme's functions.php

```
function getBetween($content,$start,$end){
$r = explode($start, $content);
if (isset($r[1])){
    $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
    return $r[0];
}
return ''; 
}
```

I tried to call above function using below code:

```
<?php
    $content_post = get_post($my_postid);
    $content = $content_post->post_content;
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    $start = ' https://example.com/';
    $end = '"';
    $output = getBetween($content,$start,$end);
    echo $start.$output; ?>
```

It gives output like below on custompage but not able to do anything while dealing with posts already published because server overwhelmed with httpd requests.

```
https://example.com/some-thing-is-here.html
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you able to get current page post id in functions.php file?

Comment: yeah, I think it's definite because when I use the same function + code call the function together on custompage it works more than fine. when I apply on all posts server got lot of httpd requests that halt the systerm, I think optimization of this code is needed that I don't know anything about.

Comment: As I have checked your code is working fine on localhost (Local machine).

Comment: thanks for giving it a test, it's obviously working more than fine on single post when I placed on every post so server got halted because definitely every website can contain hundreds of individual posts instead.

Comment: hmm, right bro.

Comment: is it possible, code having less impact while working on single post and once I applied it through my website so immediately lot of extra requests received by server to overwhelm it?

Comment: I think you can put your code in if condition if(is_single($post_id)){ } to avoid it to be used in multiple request. I hope it will make sense you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code at the `functions.php` file. It will work as tested at my localhost. I hope it will also work for you.

```
    function getBetween($content,$start,$end){
    $r = explode($start, $content);

    if (isset($r[1])){
        $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
        return $r[0];
    }
    return ''; 
    }

    $thePostID = 1;
    $content_post = get_post($thePostID);
    $content = $content_post->post_content;
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
    //print_r($content);
    $start = 'http://localhost/testing_wordpress/';
    $end = '"';
    $output = getBetween($content,$start,$end);
    echo $start.$output;
```

Comment: Hey, It doesn't work with all individual posts separately while placing function code into functions.php, mostly it returns URL of the post youre currently browsing instead of desired url. So find single.php or footer.php or header.php file in your theme and place the function as well as code to call this function in the same file then It'll work more than fine without any issue.

Comment: I was also trying this function and code to call this function using Ad-Injection plugin but it was just return url of the post I was browsing don't know why but it was happening this way.